# Using LineReciever with Twisted Process protocols

Tags: twisted

I'm trying to use twisted to handle data generated by a binary (which indefinitely dumps lines onto stdout). Since by data is inherently line-delimited, I was trying to used the LineReciever instead of trying to parse data. The following is the relevant bit of the code which seems to be causing trouble :

```
class ProtocolBareQDAL41xB(ProcessProtocol, LineReceiver):
    ...   
    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "Got Data:" + repr(data)
        self.dataReceived(data)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "Got Line: " + line
        self._process_line(line)
    ...
```

This 'works' for the first of two lines in the output. I don't know yet if it works for only one line, or if it works for all but the last line. The resulting output looks something like :

```
$ python BareQDAL41xB.py 
Made Connection
<Process pid=16486 status=-1>
Got Data:'No device found!\nMultiple devices found! Please connect only one.\n'
Got Line: No device found!
Got Serial Number :  found!
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 101, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 597, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 274, in doRead
    return fdesc.readFromFD(self.fd, self.dataReceived)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/fdesc.py", line 94, in readFromFD
    callback(output)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 277, in dataReceived
    self.proc.childDataReceived(self.name, data)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 931, in childDataReceived
    self.proto.childDataReceived(name, data)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 604, in childDataReceived
    self.outReceived(data)
  File "BareQDAL41xB.py", line 104, in outReceived
    self.dataReceived(data)
  File "/media/ldata/code/virtualenvs/tendril/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 573, in dataReceived
    self.transport.disconnecting):
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'disconnecting'

processExited, status 0
processEnded, status 0
```

LineReciever seems to be expecting the transport to implement `disconnecting`.

Is it possible to use twisted's LineReciever with twisted's ProcessProtocol, or should I implement the line parser in my protocol instead?

Comment: You've rediscovered [issue #6606](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6606)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LineReceiver` is already a `Protocol`, which implements different interfaces than `IProcessProtocol`.

Luckily, recent versions of Twisted already contain an adapter that does what you want - which is to treat a subprocess as a stream of bytes. Rather than calling `spawnProcess` directly, use [`ProcessEndpoint`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.ProcessEndpoint.html), and you can pass a regular `ProtocolFactory`, no `ProcessProtocol` involved.

However, as a commenter has already pointed out, [there's a bug here](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6606), where the `disconnecting` attribute is not formally part of `ITransport`, but `LineReceiver` (and `LineOnlyReceiver`) depend on it anyway, and since it's not part of the interface, `ProcessEndpoint` doesn't implement it.  That should definitely be fixed, but in the meanwhile, we'll need to work around it.

As a happy accident, Twisted's built-in support for wrapping protocols, [`WrappingFactory`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.protocols.policies.WrappingFactory.html), already has support for the `disconnecting` attribute, specifically because of this ugly disparity between the theory of the interface specifications and the reality of the most popular `ITransport` implementations.  So even a do-nothing wrapper will work around the problem.  You can implement this like so:

```
from zope.interface import implementer
from twisted.internet.interfaces import IStreamClientEndpoint
from twisted.protocols.policies import WrappingFactory

@implementer(IStreamClientEndpoint)
class DisconnectingWorkaroundEndpoint(object):
    def __init__(self, endpoint):
        self._endpoint = endpoint

    def connect(self, protocolFactory):
        return self._endpoint.connect(WrappingFactory(protocolFactory))
```

and then when you construct your `ProcessEndpoint`, do:

```
endpoint = DisconnectingWorkaroundEndpoint(ProcessEndpoint(...))
```

Sorry for the delay on answering; while you've probably worked out your own workaround, I hope this will be useful to others with the same question!